# include in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How we can include a thread group in JMeter in the same test plan
I have two thread groups in the same test plan

```
thread group 1

thread group 2
```

I want to include the `thread group 1` to the `thread group 2` 
is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can't actually make one THREADGROUP a child to another THREADGROUP. This is because each threadgroup specifies the number of threads and duration.  Jmeter doesn't support nested threadgroups.

You have two options. Either way, do the following

Select all elements in THREADGROUP 2, RIGHT CLICK and add a parent controller of "Simple Controller" named "master simple controller" (for clarity)

Option 1. In threadgroup 2, move the master simple controller into threadgroup 1
Option 2. Create a MODULE CONTROLLER in threadgroup 1 and point it to the master simple controller

Comment: Thank You this is the method is used